# angular 5 convert value to string in *ngFor

Tags: angular5

I have following div block , where I am iterating on observable 
Next when I try to set a ngStyle , I am getting the value of ngStyle as  [Object object] instead of string .

```
 <div class = "circle-logo-btm pull-left cp" *ngFor= "let imageUrl of (allAppBGIMageURLs$ | async)" (click)="selectApplication(1)">
              <div [ngStyle]="{'background-image':'url(' + imageUrl + ')'}" class=" btn-round"></div>
          </div>
```

This is the rendered result , its coming as an object instead of actual image url

```
 <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" _ngcontent-c3="" class=" btn-round" ng-reflect-ng-style="[object Object]"></div>
```

Comment: Console.log your allAppBGIMageURLs object and check !

Comment: same issue here! drives me crazy, implemented a toString() which is called, but results always in [Object object] (angular 7)